# Single reputation change entry missing from "Recent achievements"

Tags: bug, reputation, achievements-dialog

There are well-known, well-understood issues with the websocket connection getting broken or otherwise hung up, which prevent live updates on the "Recent achievements" toolbar item. This is not that.

Rather, I am currently seeing live updates just fine. The most recent changes to reputation are being displayed. But, there is *one* specific update that is not being displayed in the list of reputation changes.

The item is there on my profile page's "Reputation" tab, and the actual reputation number is up-to-date. It's just that for some reason, the entry for that one change (which occurred at 19:30Z yesterday) isn't included in the list of recent reputation changes in the drop-down.

I have cleared all my cookies, even completely restarted the browser (Chrome), but the problem persists. It happens also if I log into Stack Overflow using Edge. I have not tried with other browsers, not even IE6. :)

It's not really bothering me, but I do want to make sure it's reported as a bug, because…well, it's a bug. :)

**Update:**

As of today, the missing item is now being displayed again. Obviously, I don't know if this was due to a specific fix for this exact problem, or it was related to the caching bug that was present around the same time, or it was some random glitch that just resolved itself. But I'm glad to be able to note that whatever it was, it seems to have been resolved.

I've provided this new information as an edit instead of an answer, because I don't feel it actually *answers* the question. It just renders it less important, or even moot.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what kind of change it is? Is it a one- or two-point change that has to do with a question having been deleted, for example? Those almost never appear in the "trophy list"...

Comment: Can you reproduce the bug in IE6?

Comment: Can you check https://stackoverflow.com/reputation as well, to verify/confirm that matches your expectations?

Comment: @Cindy: _"Can you be more specific about what kind of change it is?"_ -- the change in question is an answer-accepted event.

Comment: @rene:  _"Can you reproduce the bug in IE6?"_ -- sorry...is that a joke? I'm afraid I  can't actually tell if you're serious or not. The issue _does_ occur in Edge as well. I don't run any version of IE any more, but even if I did, I wouldn't have access to IE**6**. _"Can you check stackoverflow.com/reputation"_ - as I mentioned above, the change _does_ show correctly on my profile page. It is also included in the text-dump returned by the stackoverflow.com/reputation URL.

Comment: @PeterDuniho yes, mentioning IE6 was a joke with a serious tone. You mentioned websockets as maybe a culprit and only one browser tested. In possible network/browsers issues ruling out local issues is key. My comment helped, you clarified and reported back on your extended testing  in a comment. Thanks for that.